# Handling authentification to Firebase Database with Fetch in a Service Worker

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, service-worker, fetch-api

I'm trying to query a Firebase database from a Service Worker using the Fetch API. However it doesn't work as expected as I can't get authenticated correctly.

Basically what I'm trying to do is from origin https://myproject.firebaseapp.com inside a Service Worker I do a call like this :

```
var fetchOptions = {};
fetchOptions.credentials = 'include';
var url = options.messageUrl;
var request = new Request('https://myproject.firebaseio.com/user/foobar.json', fetchOptions);   
messagePromise = fetch(request).then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
});
```

I'm getting this error :

```
Fetch API cannot load https://myproject.firebaseio.com/user/foobar.json. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials. Origin 'https://myproject.firebaseapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Any idea of a way to fix it? How one should do to query/update the Firebase database from a SW?

I've read https://jakearchibald.com/2014/using-serviceworker-today/ and one of the gotcha was exactly that problem, the fact that Fetch request do not send authentification.

Ideally it would be great to be able to use the Firebase JS API inside a SW but this doesn't seem to work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase doesn't store authentication info as a cookie or in anything that would be sent along in the credentials, so there's no need to send them in your fetch request. Instead, you'll need to pull the token from Firebase Auth:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(true).then(function(token) {
  // token is the value you'll need to remember for later
});
```

Once you've got the token, you should be able to add it as a query parameter to the REST request e.g. `?auth={THE_TOKEN}`. This will allow you to make your authenticated request in the Service Worker.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did what you suggested and could successfully retrieve the token, then I passed it to the SW and could successfully store it for my queries. However when I query the URL with ?token={the_token} I get a permission denied answer. As a matter of fact a curl with the same URL and the token returns the same result. Something I'm missing? Note that the rest of the app can query the firebase database just fine using PolymerFire elements (and I'm successfully logged in)

Comment: Oops! That's what I get for not refreshing myself with the docs. The param is actually `?auth=` not `?token=`. See [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-reading-data-get) for more helpful info.