# Cloud Functions for Firebase - Cannot load URL: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an angular 2 app where I'm calling a Firebase via an http request. However, anytime, I try to run the function, I'm getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://us-central1-<my-projectId>.cloudfunctions.net/getUserByEmail?email=user@email.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
    error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0  for URL: null
    ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:54
    next @ application_ref.js:348
    schedulerFn @ async.js:93
    SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:234
    SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:183
    Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
    Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
    EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
    NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333
    onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:294
    ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:338
    Zone.runTask @ zone.js:169
    ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:420
    Subscriber.js:238 Uncaught Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers…}
```

Here is my Cloud Function for Firebase `index.js` file:

```
   const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
    const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

    /**
     *  Function to get a user by email
     */
    exports.getUserByEmail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      cors(request, response, () => {

// This should return a promise from the getUserByEmail function
response.status(200).send(admin.auth().getUserByEmail(req.query.email))
       })
    });
```

And then here's how I'm calling the function in a component (assuming the HTTP request is made successfully):

```
this.http.get('https://us-central1-rosebud-9b0ed.cloudfunctions.net/getUserByEmail', {
       search: "user@email.com"
     }).subscribe(data => {
       console.log('data', data);
     })
```

It would seem that no matter what I try, I keep hitting this same issue. I've even tried deploying this to my firebase hosted URL and it still gives me this error. Anyone know what I can do here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase) though you may not have known that :)

Answer (score 21):

So I made a few key mistakes here.

1. Make sure to require `cors` before you initialize the Firebase app.
2. Make sure that the parameters march the `cors()` function.

Here is the updated `index.js` code:

```
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


    /**
     *  Function to get a user by email
     */
    exports.getUserByEmail = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      cors(request, response, () => {

// This should return a promise from the getUserByEmail function
response.status(200).send(admin.auth().getUserByEmail(req.query.email))
       })
    });
```

Comment: How would you require cors before initializing the Firebase app if I am grouping my functions in separate files? (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#group_functions)