# Cloud Functions for Firebase not setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

While attempting to get CORS working with Cloud Functions for Firebase, I tried to follow the official example here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint

However, even following the tutorial instructions as exactly as possible, I still get this error in the console:

[image: No Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header]

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I never got CORS working, but the workaround I found was to use hosting redirects for the functions. That way, HTTP function calls are not cross site at all.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions (See "Direct Hosting requests to your function")

```js
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",

    // Add the following rewrites section *within* "hosting"
   "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "/api/bigben", "function": "bigben"
    } ]

  }
}
```

Note: I have to define a redirect for every endpoint. Is there a way to have general rewrites? e.g.

```
"source": "/api/*", "function": "*"
```

Comment: this is very helpful! thank you!! was stuck on cors for the entire day...

Answer (score 0):

Try following this ?

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/42756623/6650162
>
> [Handling CORS in Google Cloud Functions](https://mhaligowski.github.io/blog/2017/03/10/cors-in-cloud-functions.html)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes those are good pages for reference. I couldn't get it working even with that help though... :/

Comment: you try insert ?   "headers" : [ {
    "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "value" : "*"
  } ]

Comment: Yeah I tried that in like 5 different ways. But it would send a pre-flight OPTIONS request and that was never answered correctly I guess

Comment: For those who try the methods mentioned in this post and still not working, try rechecking your request function.

Mine was simple as removing content-type from headers from Fetch web api