# How to resolve CORS policy issue in Ionic Angular app?

Tags: angular, firebase, xmlhttprequest, cors, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to execute the below function in my Ionic Angular app, ***cloudFunctionUrl*** is a cloud function I have in my firebase project:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
private http: HttpClient

like(post) {
this.http.post('cloudFunctionUrl', JSON.stringify(body), {
      responseType: 'text'
    }).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

To get over the **CORS** issue, I installed the ***Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin*** chrome plugin. Below is a list of the whitelisted domains:

- http://localhost:8100
- chrome.google.com
- localhost
- localhost:8100
- localhost:8100/profile
- cloudFunctionUrl

The `like` function above is executed on `localhost:8100/profile`.

I'm experiencing two issueS:

1. I navigate to *localhost:8100/profile* no problem, but when I execute `like`, I get this error message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'cloudFunctionUrl' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

2. If I go to the firebase console, & I have the CORS plugin turned on, it says ***"There was an error loading your projects"***

Can someone please tell me how I can resolve this?

I also tried to add the below headers to the request, but the error is still appearing:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
    this.http.post('cloudFunctionUrl', JSON.stringify(body), {
      headers: headers,
      responseType: 'text'
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to execute `cloudFunctionUrl` (cloud function) from your Ionic Angular app.

**I also tried to add the below headers to the request, but the error is still appearing**

You have to add the heather in your cloud function, not in the Angular App. Your Angular App will call the function, and your function will return the required headers, allowing your App to access data from cloud function.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
```

Your cloud function has to support CORS requests from your Angular App, node.js example:

```
/**
 * HTTP function that supports CORS requests.
 *
 * @param {Object} req Cloud Function request context.
 * @param {Object} res Cloud Function response context.
 */
exports.corsEnabledFunction = (req, res) => {
  // Set CORS headers for preflight requests
  // Allows GETs from any origin with the Content-Type header
  // and caches preflight response for 3600s

  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.status(204).send('');
  } else {
    res.send('Hello World!');
  }
};
```

[Handling CORS requests](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [Handling CORS requests](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests) explains that:

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a way to let applications running on one domain access content from another domain, for example, letting yourdomain.com make requests to region-project.cloudfunctions.net/yourfunction.

In that documentation, you can get more clarification on the use of CORS  on Cloud Functions.

Usually adding the below code, helps the use of CORS on Firebase - as per this post on the Community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase) indicates.

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
```

However, it might be the case, that this won't be enough to solve your case. For this reason, I could find some useful cases from the Community, of users facing similar errors with CORS in the usage of Cloud Functions and Angular.

I would recommend you to take a look at them below, so you can get more information on what might be affecting your application and what might help you fix it as well.

- [Google Cloud Functions enable CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693758/google-cloud-functions-enable-cors)
- [Enable Cors in Firebase Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326098/enable-cors-in-firebase-cloud-function)
- [Unable to test locally using firebase due to CORS restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49856240/unable-to-test-locally-using-firebase-due-to-cors-restriction)

Let me know if the information helped you!