# Firebase callable functions giving me CORS issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I've been trying callable functions to avoid handling cors manually but so far nothing is working

[image]

i've read similar issue [Firebase Callable Function + CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278537/firebase-callable-function-cors)

the difference is the that dude has 'no access control allow origin' issue. Mine is response to preflight ... issue

I'd like to request for a guidance people. It's frustrating argh..

I'm on Blaze plan

So far i've been trying only to run the functions Locally. i have not deployed the function at all.

this is my function code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();


exports.createOrder = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(data)
        .then(result => {
            return result;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err.code);
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', err.message);
        });
});
```

});
this is my client code

```
export const createOrder = order => {
    functions
        .httpsCallable('createOrder')({ data: order })
        .then(result => {
            console.log('result create order is', result);

            return result;
        });
};
```

functions package.json

```
{
    "name": "functions",
    "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
        "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
        "start": "npm run shell",
        "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
        "logs": "firebase functions:log"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.4.0",
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "firebase": "^6.3.1",
        "firebase-admin": "^8.2.0",
        "firebase-functions": "^3.1.0",
        "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "8"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

firebase config.json

```
"firebase": {
            "apiKey": "AIzaSy*****",
            "authDomain": "jokii-test.firebaseapp.com",
            "databaseURL": "https://jokii-test.firebaseio.com",
            "projectId": "jokii-test",
            "storageBucket": "jokii-test.appspot.com",
            "messagingSenderId": "104544.....",
            "appId": "1:10454485....."
        }
```

Firebase SDK =  "firebase": "^6.3.1",

Comment: Does the function works if you deploy it? Had similar problems once now i test my functions deployed. Would be nice if someone knows a solution but at the moment this maybe helps you to keep working on your project.

Comment: @Sebe it worked once i deployed the function @@

Answer (score 1):

The client SDK doesn't know how to access a function that hasn't been deployed.  Notice in the error output that the URL it's trying to access is the one for your fully deployed function.  It's currently not possible to have it override the URL to access one you're running locally on localhost.

If you want to invoke your callable function locally, you'll need to implement a client that follows the [protocol specification for callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).  And, as you can see, that's going to be a fair amount of work, because the client SDK is managing a lot of the HTTP protocol work for you.

Comment: i see.. i did not read that part. thanks for clarifying the issue doug. Your firebase videos on youtube helped a lot : )