# Fail to call firebase 'onCall' function in front end due to CORS policy

Tags: firebase, vue.js, cors, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a function which can get the data from database of Firebase.
So I wrote the following simple function to see if I can call him on the front-end page.
But I received the error message :

> Access to fetch at
>   'https://us-central1-undefined.cloudfunctions.net/sayHello' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Code in '**index.js**':

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.sayHello = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const name = data.name;
  return `hello ${name} :)`.then(()=>{
    console.log('success');
  }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
});
```

Code in the component which calls the function:

```
import { db, functions, rootRef } from '../db/firebaseConfig.js';

methods: {
  sayHello(){
    const sayHello = functions.httpsCallable('sayHello');
    // call the function and pass data
    sayHello({ name: 'Peter' }).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
     });
  },
```

I have also read the answer [Enabling CORS in Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase).
But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you show how you have implemented the solution presented in the answer you mention (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42756623/3371862)? It is actually THE solution.

Comment: I added the code ```const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});``` and I updated the firebase functions to the latest version.

Comment: Actually, I realise now that you are using a Callable Cloud Function, not an HTTPS one. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278537/firebase-callable-function-cors

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the functions emulator?
If so you need to set it like so

```
firebase.initializeApp(config)
firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator("http://localhost:5001")
```

(Change 5001 port to the port you use)