# Firebase callable cloud function CORS error, but allUsers is already set as invoker

Tags: firebase, function, cloud, hosting, vuejs3

Thank you for any help you could provide. I will be brief to save your time!

I have a cloud function (done following the official youtube tutorial):

```
exports.makeAdminUser = functions.region('europe-central2').https.onCall( (data, context) => {
   grantAdminRole( data.email )
})
```

I have an invocation (done following the official documentation, from a vuejs app):

```
const addAdmin = functions.httpsCallable('makeAdminUser')
addAdmin({ email: 'x@x.com'}).then( res => { console.log( res ) })
```

I have the permissions set for the deployed function (allUsers as the invoker, the function is public, doesn't require authentication):
[image]

I get a CORS error, like so (trying to invoke from firebase hosting):
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onCall functions behaviour differently than onRequest functions with regards to the cors, for example you need to ensure you're calling it from the same region. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278537/firebase-callable-function-cors)

Example:

```
const addAdmin = functions('europe-west2').httpsCallable('makeAdminUser')
addAdmin({ email: 'x@x.com'}).then( res => { console.log( res ) })
```

The cors issue can also occur if your function is erroring, worth checking in your local emmulator.

Comment: Thank you, the issue was the calling of the function. It automatically called from us-central1, although the functions was declared in europe-central2. The cors library was not needed.