# Testing an `https.onCall` function for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to test an `https.onCall` function but I keep getting `Access to fetch at 'https://<project>.cloudfunctions.net/<func>' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

I've also tried running it in the emulator, but I get the same result because the ports don't match. I have no idea how to enable CORS for an `onCall` function.

Comment: Have you checked [Firebase callable functions + cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278537/firebase-callable-function-cors?) ?

Comment: I have, but none of it seemed to help.

Comment: If the accepted answer from[1] did not shed some light, can you please add a reproducible piece of code to the question? or share a redacted github repo?
[1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278537/firebase-callable-function-cors?