# Following the documentation gives CORS policy errors on my Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

I have a web app that is already using Firebase for authentications and also Firestore. I want to call my function from the web app so I am using `onCall` because it's recommended by [Functions documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd).

When I run my web app on localhost, I got this error: `blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Server:

```
import { onCall, HttpsError } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import { onDocumentWritten } from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";

import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";

exports.plusone = onCall({
    cors: true,
}, (request) => {
    const email = request.auth?.token.email;
    const num = request.data.num;

    logger.log(email + " tried to increase his number by one:" + num);

    return {
        finalNum: num + 1,
    }
})
```

Client:

```
const functions = getFunctions();
const plusone = httpsCallable(
  functions, 'plusone'
)
plusone().then((result) => {
    console.log(result.data.message)
})
```

Update:
Also, I do think I gave the necessary permissions:
[image: allUsers have Cloud Run Invoker permission]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Comment: All the answers aren't using onCall, so they have request and response in their arguments. Meanwhile mine only has one

Comment: this might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62042554/10249176

Comment: I followed that post and I think #5 could be a possible reason. I gave all users invoker permission and still got the error. Cloud logging said Invalid request, unable to process. I don't know the next step

Comment: I got it working when I deleted everything and set up everything again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the entire firebase functions folder and restarted from scratch and the error is gone.