# How to solve CORS in firebase functions enviroment?

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I´m runnig into `CORS` issues. In my `functions/index.js` I have:

```
const cors = require('cors')({
  origin: true
});
```

My endpoint is `https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago`. I need to do a `POST` to this url with apropiate parameters from the client, and this is outside firebase enviroment. I also have the correct plan to allow external network, but making a request to a different address than the origin one, triggers a `CORS` problem:

- [error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guUUX.jpg)
- [network log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WDfa.jpg)

I have read that you only need to modify the headers, but that only applies if you are making a request to your own server. When you do the `http.onRequest()`, you can use a middleware inside the function, but what happens when you make a POST to an external server?

This is the `axios` functions that do the `POST`:

```
cardPay: function () {
  this.cardProcess = true
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://us-central1-cutre-windrider.cloudfunctions.net/cardPay',
      data: {
        verifiedUserLogged: this.userLogged.uid,
        cart: this.cartItemList,
        finalPrice: this.serverPrice,
        deliveryInfo: this.userLogged.deliveryAdress,
        name: this.userLogged.displayName || false,
        email: this.userLogged.email
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      this.requestData = response
      this.redsysRedirect(response.data.data)
    })
    .catch(console.log)
    },
redsysRedirect: function (data) {
  axios.post('https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago', {
    'Ds_SignatureVersion': 'HMAC_SHA256_V1',
    'Ds_MerchantParameters': data.merchantParameters,
    'Ds_Signature': data.signature
  }).then(console.log).catch(console.log)
```

These are the server side functions:

```
exports.cardPay = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return cors(req, res, () => {
    const cart = req.body.cart
    const user = req.body.verifiedUserLogged
    const key = admin.database().ref(`sales/${user}`).push().key
    processCart(cart).then(result => {
      console.info(createPayment(result, key))
      return res.json({ "data": createPayment(result, key) }).end()
    }).catch(console.log)
  })
})

function processCart(cart) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Promise.all(cart.map(i => switcher(i)))
      .then(prices => resolve(
        prices.reduce(
          (finalPrice, price) => price + finalPrice, 0)
      )).catch(console.log)
  });
}

function switcher(item) {
  switch (item.destiny) {
    case 'bookedLessons':
        return lessonPrice(item.name, item.index)
      case 'bookedRentals':
        return rentalPrice(item.id, item.index, item.insurancePurchased, item.insuranceId)
      case 'bookedLodgins':
        return item.reservationData ? roomPriceWithReservation(item.id, item.quantity, item.persons, item.reservationData) : roomPriceNoReservation(item.id, item.quantity, item.persons)
      case 'deliveries':
        return productPrice(item.id, item.quantity)
      case 'bookedCar':
        return carPrice(item.id, item.index)
      case 'bookedStorage':
        return storagePrice(item.index)
      case 'bookedTransportation':
        return transportationPrice(item.id, item.index, item.persons, item.roundTrip)
      case 'bookedDoublePack':
        return doublePack(item.id, item.persons)
      case 'bookedTriplePack':
        return triplePack(item.id, item.persons)
      default:
        break
  }
}

function createPayment(total, orderId) {
  let redsys = new Redsys();
  let mParams = {
      "DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT":total.toString(),
      "DS_MERCHANT_ORDER":orderId,
      "DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE":   "025988262",
      // "DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE":tpvInfo.fucCode,
      "DS_MERCHANT_CURRENCY":"978",
      // "DS_MERCHANT_CURRENCY":tpvInfo.currency,
      "DS_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONTYPE":"0",
      // "DS_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONTYPE":tpvInfo.transaction_type,
      "DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL":   "001",
      // "DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL":tpvInfo.terminal,
      "DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTURL":'http://localhost:8080',
      "DS_MERCHANT_URLOK":'http://localhost:8080/home?foo=true',
      "DS_MERCHANT_URLKO":'http://localhost:8080/home?foo=false'
  };
  return  {signature: redsys.createMerchantSignature(/* tpvInfo.secret */   "sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7", mParams) , merchantParameters: redsys.createMerchantParameters(mParams), raw: mParams};
}
```

Answer (score 25):

For someone who will meet this issue in the future (or my future self):

If you've already configured CORS using `cors` package, and you think you configured it correctly, and still have CORS error in the browser console, check this article:

https://haha.world/firebase-cors/

Basically, it's a misleading error returns from Google Cloud Functions, when actually the error is inside your code logic (which is totally not related to CORS at all)

So the first step to fix this bug is to check Google Cloud Functions logs (or Firebase Cloud Functions logs) to see if your function crashed because of any error in your code. Then fix it.

---

***Note***: For someone that doesn't have the issue that I described above, you can see other answers, or check these resources:

1. https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html
2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps

Comment: For me, the issue was that I needed to re-export the Google credentials file. If CORS worked for you before, ignore this error and look for the issue elsewhere.

Comment: watch out for "Unhadled rejection" in your firebase logs

Comment: wow. that was it. error in function, returning cors error.

Comment: Absolutely true! In my case I was calling the "test" function using "Test" string and I was getting a CORS related error.

Answer (score 9):

Within your Firebase Function response header you could explicitly allow all origins:

```
exports.handler = ((req, res) => {
    res.set({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }).sendStatus(200)
})
```

Or you could modify this to allow only specific origins. This is generally how I have worked around CORS issues with Firebase funcitons in the past.

Comment: and then the response res.json({foo: bar})? because this overwrites the headers, and cause a `Can't set headers after they are sent`

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to send a json response you could do this:

`res.set({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }).status(200).json({foo: bar})`

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' is pretty dangerous, is there not a safer way to test your functions from a local app?

Answer (score 9):

Check out https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests .  From that document -

```
exports.corsEnabledFunction = (req, res) => {
  // Set CORS headers
  // e.g. allow GETs from any origin with the Content-Type header
  // and cache preflight response for an 3600s
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
  // Send response to OPTIONS requests and terminate the function execution
  if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(204).send('');
  }
  // Continue with function code
  ...
}
```

Comment: In the documentation you attached, specify how to handle CORS when using firebase functions: `yourdomain.com` make requests to region-`project.cloudfunctions.net/yourfunction`, but this is not the case, In that case you can access `yourfunction`, but I have to make a `POST` to a site that is not a function. Unless you're referring to configuring them globally, by the way, I'm not using Express.

Comment: Any way you can add these same headers to the response from https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago? If so, this should work even if it isn't cloud functions.

Comment: `sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago` is just the url to where I need to `POST`, I won't get a response until the request is made to that url. Using the anwser of @Jason Dark: `res.set({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }).sendStatus(200)
      return res.send(200, { "data": createPayment(result, key) }).end();` this cause a `Can't set headers after they are sent`.

Comment: What happens when you try what I mentioned above? The answer from @jasonDark has a flaw in that it sends a response code all the time which is why you're getting the error. Also, it doesn't send a 204 status code in response to the preflight core options.

It might be worth reading through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS for more info on CORS.

Comment: I've spent way too much time looking for this! Well done

Answer (score 1):

I have also spent 1 entire day on finding the CORS related issue for Firebase functions.

Finally, I found the solution.

By default, firebase-functions are **not available** to access on internet, we have to create a principle for it & assign to that function.

1. Go to your GCP console dashboard:

   https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard
2. Search "Cloud Functions" in the top Search input, go to "Cloud Functions".
3. Then, select your cloud function (checkbox).
4. Click on Permissions on top, after selecting your function.
5. Click on "Add Principal".
6. Type "allUsers" as the principal name and select the role "Cloud Function Invoker".
   *You will see a message, "Ability to invoke HTTP functions with restricted access.*
7. "Save"

That's it!

Access is now available to everybody from the internet with the correct config to your Firebase functions without CORS errors.

**See the below image here:**

[image]