# Axios second request fails with a CORS error if the first request returns a 400 but works fine if it returns a 200

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, axios, google-cloud-functions

I have a React app that gets data from an Express API. I have a function that updates some data and then refetch the data. It works fine when the update succeeds (with a code 200). But when the update fails (with a code 409 for example), the request made after to fetch the data again fails with a CORS error. CORS is configured in the backend so I don't know where this could be coming from.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at THE_URL from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The update failing is a normal behaviour. for example the user could be trying to activate an element that already is activated. When that happens the API returns a 409 error. So, when I get a 409, the GET function made direclty after to fetch the data completely fails. The Axios error message is `Network Error`.

The API is hosted on Firebase functions if that helps.

***Edit***
The backend is using cors library to handle this. Here is the code:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as cors from 'cors';

import healthCheck from '../../common/utils/healthCheck';
import initFullPath from '../../common/middleware/initFullPath';
import validateFirebaseIdToken from '../../common/middleware/validateFirebaseToken';

import cortexRoutes from './routes/Cortex.routes';
import cameraRoutes from './routes/Camera.routes';

const app = express();
const main = express();

const API_VERSION = 'v1';

main.use(bodyParser.json());
main.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
main.use(cors({ origin: true }));
main.use(`/${API_VERSION}`, initFullPath(`/config/${API_VERSION}`), app);

app.route('/health').get(healthCheck);

app.use(validateFirebaseIdToken);
app.use(cortexRoutes);
app.use(cameraRoutes);

export default main;
```

Comment: It looks like there might be some issue with the way you have configured CORS. Could you post the code of your functions that handles CORS?
For reference, here is the Cloud Functions CORS configuration section of the docs, [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited my post.

Comment: I can see that you have 2 express instances, `main` and `app` . Correct me if I am wrong, but I assume that the failed request is handled by `main`, which is CORS enabled.

Sometimes, CORS erros may be due to underlying errors in the code execution. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57932093/12163274). I suggest you review the [Cloud Function Logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/logs?service=cloudfunctions.googleapis.com) and check if there are any other errors being thrown when you get the CORS erros

Answer (score 0):

I solved this type of issue with this,

Install `cors` - [Refer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Use it like this,

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors())
 
app.get('/....', function (req, res, next) {
  ......
})
```

Comment: The api has already cors configured. Requests work fine. Only the request made after a request with an error gets a CORS error.