# Can't deploy firebase cloud function

Tags: typescript, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions, ionic4

I'm trying to deploy a firebase cloud function with cors but it doesn't work. This is my code bellow, can someone help me with this ?

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as cors from 'cors'

admin.initializeApp()

const corsHandler = cors({origin: true})

export const getUser = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    corsHandler(request, response, () => {})

    admin.firestore().doc("profiles/T0XCPHPkrJM4I10okb9KSHyukqn1").get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.data()
        console.log(data)
        response.send(data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        response.status(500).send(error)
    })

})
```

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase?rq=1 may be helpful - it looks like their problem was similar to yours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling CORS in Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase)

Comment: I already checked it, the solution I used is on this post but it doesn't work. Oliver Dixon commented the response for Typescript, he said that "Solution will make you lose logging on cloud functions (very bad)"

Comment: did you call initializeApp properly or did you remove the rest of your code for demoing, didn't you have to reference serviceAccount.json and all that stuff.

Comment: This is all the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. You have to include the code of your asynchronous Firebase call **inside** the function.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as cors from 'cors'

admin.initializeApp()

const corsHandler = cors({origin: true})

export const getUser = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    corsHandler(request, response, () => {

        admin.firestore().doc("profiles/T0XCPHPkrJM4I10okb9KSHyukqn1").get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            const data = snapshot.data()
            console.log(data)
            response.send(data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          response.status(500).send(error)
        })

    })

})
```

Comment: It works now, thank you very much! You saved my day!