# send form data to firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to send data from my javascript web page to firebase cloud function (HTTP Request).

I have seen a few tutorials on using Busboy, but that is at the cloud function side. What I want to know is how do I send it to the function from client side web page.

As given in the Google Cloud Functions [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#multipart_data), I have used the following code in my Firebase Function.

```
...
busboy.on('field', (fieldname, val) => {
    // TODO(developer): Process submitted field values here
    console.log(`Processed field ${fieldname}: ${val}.`);
    fields[fieldname] = val;
  });
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a "standard" [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), you need to issue an HTTP request from your Web page, with JavaScript. One way to do that is by using the [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library.

It is quite simple:

You declare the library in the head part of your html page

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
```

And, in your JavaScript code, you call the Cloud Function through its URL. Here is an example with a POST Request:

```
axios.post('https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/<your-cloud-cunction-name>', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    //Do whatever you wantwith the response object, returned by the HTTPS Cloud Function
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

In the Cloud Function you would do `req.body.firstName` and `req.body.lastName` to get the values passed in the body of the POST Request. If you don't need to pass values through the request's body, you may use a GET method (and possibly pass some values through Query String).

---

If you want, in the Cloud Function, to use the 'busboy' library to parse a `'multipart/form-data'` upload request (as shown in the example you refer to in your question) the following Stack Overflow answer explains how to do it with axios:

[axios post request to send form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data?rq=1)

---

Note that Firebase offers another type of HTTP Cloud Function: the [HTTPS Callable Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

With this type you can call it from your web front-end using the dedicated Cloud Functions client library provided by Firebase. The documentation shows the following example:

```
var addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addMessage');
addMessage({text: messageText}).then(function(result) {
  // Read result of the Cloud Function.
  var sanitizedMessage = result.data.text;
  // ...
});
```

Have a look at the doc, which explains all the steps (how to write the Cloud Function and how to call it) into detail.

Comment: Is there any other way without using any external library like axios?

Comment: Yes, you could make an HTTP call in Ajax or use jQuery methods (see this doc https://medium.freecodecamp.org/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa) but I would advise to use Axios, which is quite user friendly and also returned Promises (which is in line with the Firebase Web/JavaScript SDK way of handling asynchronous tasks)

Comment: @BasilVictor See my update on how to send `'multipart/form-data'` upload requests

Comment: i have implemented the axios, but there appears to be an error. Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-test-ec013.cloudfunctions.net/addData' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Can you please tell me a quick fix.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54102360/cant-deploy-firebase-cloud-function/54106882#54106882

Comment: Yes callable functions are working for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know, that axios is not the best solution for objects like formData (pics and others), may will be better if you use fetch?