# Problem with Post API: "has been blocked by CORS policy...."

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am using this code in React app, it supposed to fire a notification to react native expo app. instead, i am getting this error in the browser's console.

i tried adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods...etc

```
let response = fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          to: token,
          sound: 'default',
          title: 'Demo',
          body: 'Demo notificaiton'
        })
      });
```

Comment: Hi, do you mind uploading your setupProxy.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to have an API that allows CORS, or the call has to be made to the same domain as the front-end.  If you don't have access to the API server to allow CORS you need to add a proxy server.  I've always relied on express for that, set up a local API that is the same domain as your front-end, then have the express API make the actual fetch call to the API server.

Comment: Hi, i am currently using firebase as my backend and hence cannot use express, how can i solve this ?

Comment: @kd12345 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Answer (score 3):

Proxy any unknown requests to your API server in development, add a proxy field to your package.json, for example:

> "proxy": "http://localhost:4000",

[Read more](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)