# Cloud Function Firebase request.body is undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

User side: POST method using fetch function:

```js
let response = await fetch(url, {
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "body": JSON.stringify({"stripeToken": token.id})
});
```

Server side: URL to fetch is a Firebase Cloud Function:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const stripe = require("stripe")("PRIVATE_KEY");

exports.chargeStripe = functions.https.onRequest( async (request, response) => {

    // Getting token
    let token = request.body.stripeToken;

    // Creating charge
    let charge = await stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 99,
        currency: 'eur',
        description: 'Payment',
        source: token
    });

    // Sending response
    charge ? send(response, 200, {message: 'Success'}) : send(response, 500, {message: 'Error!'});

});
```

The problem is that I am getting `console.log(token) → 'undefined'`.

### Update 1

It seems that Chrome (browser) is blocking the fetch function (CORS policy). If I test the end-point via Insomnia, everything is working fine.

So, someone knows what to do in this case?

### Update 2

Thanks to [Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541821/cloud-function-firebase-request-body-is-undefined?noredirect=1#comment103408390_58541821), I added CORS middleware inside the function:

```js
exports.chargeStripe = functions.https.onRequest( (request, response) => {

    // Enable CORS using the `cors` express middleware.
    return cors(request, response, async () => {

        // Reading token
        let token = request.body.stripeToken;

        // Charging user
        let charge = await stripe.charges.create({
            amount: 99,
            currency: 'eur',
            description: 'Payment',
            source: token
        });

        // Sending response 
        response.status(200).send('Ok');
    });

});
```

Now everything works!

Comment: I'm not sure your implementation of cors is correct. The preflight request isn't going to contain the actual post data. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Comment: Ok, I edit the question because maybe it can lead to confusion.

Comment: It still doesn't look like you're implementing cors properly.  All you're doing is importing the library.  You need to use it in the function as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience, Doug Stevenson. Updated my question again...

Comment: If you have the solution to your own problem, you should add it as an answer so the question can be closed with the correct answer accepted.

Comment: Done! Thanks again, you made my day! I have been struggling with this for hours...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42756623/9504458), I added the `cors package`:

```js
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
```

And then, I used CORS middleware inside the function. So, the final solution is:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const stripe = require("stripe")("PRIVATE_KEY");

exports.chargeStripe = functions.https.onRequest( (request, response) => {

    // Enable CORS using the `cors` express middleware.
    return cors(request, response, async () => {

        // Reading token
        let token = request.body.stripeToken;

        // Charging user
        let charge = await stripe.charges.create({
            amount: 99,
            currency: 'eur',
            description: 'Payment',
            source: token
        });

        // Sending response 
        response.status(200).send('Ok');
    });

});
```