# Firebase Cloud Function CORS issue in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

i know there are tons of CORS post and solutions and i been going through them many times. No luck to resolve my CORS issue after hours and i decided to post here :)

my client angular method
imported and initialized package

```
...import { AngularFireFunctions } from "@angular/fire/functions";
  constructor(...
    private afn: AngularFireFunctions,
  ) {}
```

```
  initCloudFunctions() {
    let cmd = "helloWorld";
    const callable = this.afn.httpsCallable(cmd);
    let data = callable({ name: "some-data" }).subscribe({
      next(res) {
        console.log("res: ", res);
      },
      error(msg) {
        console.log("Error : ", msg);
      }
    });
  }
```

My firebase cloud-function (in TypeScript), index.ts

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // let url = 'https://a1rvv0rk2.stackblitz.io/main/firecp'
    // response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', url);
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')

    response.send("Hello from Firebase! " + new Date());
});
```

i have used wildcard but yet i still get CORS error

> Access to fetch at 'https://...my project
>   ....cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld' from origin 'https://..my project
>   ....stackblitz.io'  has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header
>   field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
>   preflight response. zone.js:1118 
>   POST https://...my project
>   .....cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld net::ERR_FAILED

really appreciate if i could get some helps from gurus.

Updates:
Thanks Doug, and [Lars from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0rZnxRV7_k), i managed to import CORS successfully!
here my updated code and hope it helps for those using TypeScript rather than JavaScript

*import CORS lib*

```
import * as corsModule from 'cors'
const cors = corsModule(({ origin: true }))
```

*Cloud Function*

```
export const helloWorldWithCORS = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    // ref: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1338#issuecomment-461234192
    cors(request, response, () => {
        response.status(200).send({data: { success: true, message: 'yeah!' }})
    })
});
```

*Angular App*

```
 async initCloudFunctions() {
    // let cmd = "helloWorld";
    let cmd = "helloWorldWithCORS";
    const callable = this.afn.httpsCallable(cmd);

    this.data = await callable({name: 'some data'})
    console.log(this.data)
  }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete, minimal code of the Cloud Function code that doesn't work the way you expect.  What you have right now is a few lines taken out of context.

Comment: @DougStevenson, sorry for the ugly code. i updated with least code as i can coz the whole script is too long and not relevant to show here. :)

Comment: FYI there is a cors module that handles all this for you, which is much easier.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Comment: i read tht post, but i also found the reply under the post, by deanwilliammills, which is must easier. i thought it will work https://stackoverflow.com/a/51922520/8163746 shouldn't it?

Comment: hi @DougStevenson, Thanks again for the pointer and i managed to get rid of CORS issue in TypeScript (codes updated above). 
May i know what's stopping my client app output result from cloud function as i have already using 'await'. 
Also, i noticed it must return 'data' object to avoid error 'Response is missing data field'

Comment: Please tell me you found a fix.

Comment: Yes, i found the fix @RubenSzekér

Answer (score -2):

Try adding an additional allow-header:

```
  response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type')
```

This should be implicit according to mozzilla docs:

> The CORS-safelisted request headers, Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type are always allowed and don't need to be listed by this header necessarily. However, note that additional restrictions apply with these headers which you circumvent by listing these headers in an Access-Control-Allow-Headers header as well.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Still possibly additional locks can be present

Comment: hi @matteo, i added your code (as shown in updated code) but still getting same error. :)