# Cloud Storage Set CORS to allow download Firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a firebase function which serves a website as per below:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("my-website"));
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Where `my-website` has `my-website/subfolder/index.html` and `my-website/subfolder/index.js`. I have deployed the function and it successfully serves up `index.html` and `index.js`. However, `index.js` is attempting to download a file from Cloud Storage but is getting the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/my-project.appspot.com/my-project-files/data.csv' from origin 'https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I am not using the firebase cloud storage web library, because the code is already written using the `d3.js` library as per below, and I can't change it:

```
d3.queue()
    .defer(
      d3.csv,
      "https://storage.cloud.google.com/my-project.appspot.com/my-project-files/data.csv"
    )
    .defer(d3.json, "data/config.json")
    .defer(d3.json, "data/geog.json")
    .await(ready);
```

This code generates the following request:

```
:authority: storage.cloud.google.com
:method: GET
:path: /my-project.appspot.com/my-project-files/data.csv
:scheme: https
accept: text/csv,*/*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
origin: https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/app/my-website/subfolder/index.html
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36
```

I have set a CORS policy on my bucket to allow requests from my cloud functions, `gsutil cors get gs://my-project.appspot.com` returns:

```
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, 
"method": ["GET"], 
"origin": ["https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net"], 
"responseHeader": ["Content-Type"]}]
```

I am not sure where to go from here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling CORS in Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common error for people setting up webapps. To make sure that sites are secure and to prevent code injections, browsers prevent cross-origin requests. Mozilla has a great manual on how to solve this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors

Answer (score 0):

I worked out that the problem is the Cloud Storage doesn't actually let you allow CORS for the `storage.cloud.google.com`, instead you have to use `storage.googleapis.com`.