# Connection Refused Error on React using env Variables from Docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, environment-variables

I'm trying to define some env variables in my docker files, in order to use these in my react application:

The next is my docker file in the Node server side:

```
FROM node:lts-slim

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app
# install node_modules
ADD package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install --loglevel verbose
# copy codebase to docker codebase
ADD . /app

EXPOSE 8081

# You can change this
CMD [ "nodemon", "serverApp.js" ]
```

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    stdin_open: true
    container_name: firestore_manager
    build:
      context: ./client/firestore-app
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    image: rasilvap/firestore_manager
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./client/firestore-app:/app
    environment:
      - BACKEND_HOST=backend
      - BACKEND_PORT=8081
    depends_on:
      - backend
  backend:
    container_name: firestore_manager_server
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: rasilvap/firestore_manager_server
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
```

This is the way in which I'm using it in the react code:

```
axios.delete(`http://backend:8081/firestore/`, request).then((res) => {....
```

But I'm getting a connection refused Error. I'm new with react and not pretty sure how can I achieve this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your way of requesting the service looks fine  : `http://foo-service:port`.
I think that your issue is a security issue.
Because the two applications are not considered on the same origin (origin = domain + protocol + port), you fall into into a [CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) requirement.
In that scenario, your browser will not accept to perform your ajax query if the backend didn't return a its agreement to the preflight CORS request to share its resources with that other "origin".
So enable CORS in the backend to solve the issue (each api/framework has its own way).
Maybe [that post](http://%20%20%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase) may help you for firebase.

Comment: It seems like the server is not found: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED