# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - Firebase Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cors

I created a GET request using firebase functions. I can receive data using Postman, but not from my FE application.

While accessing the endpoints i'm getting this error

```
from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My FE Code,

```
  pay() {
    this.http.get(this.settings.createPaymentRequest).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

Server Code,

```
exports.createRequest = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
const cors = require('cors')({
  origin: '*'
});
...
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/payment-requests/',
    form: payload,
    headers: insta_headers,
    json: true
  };

  return rp(options)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.success) {

        db.collection('PAYMENT_REQUESTS').doc(response.payment_request.id).set({
          LONG_URL: response.payment_request.longurl,
          REQUEST_CREATED_AT: response.payment_request.created_at,
          PAYMENT_STATUS: "STARTED"
        }, {
          merge: true
        }).then(function () {
          response.setHeader(headers);
          res.status(200).send({
            STATUS: "SUCCESS",
            RESPONSE: response.payment_request.longurl
          });
        })
          .catch(function (error) {
            res.status(200).send({
              STATUS: "ERROR",
              RESPONSE: error
            });
          });



      } else return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');

    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.log("ERROR" + e);
      res.status(200).send({
        STATUS: "ERROR",
        RESPONSE: e
      });
    });
});
```

Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you create this

```
const cors = require('cors')({
  origin: '*'
});
```

but don't inject it anywhere (unless that is part of the `...`)

There should be something like this somewhere

```
app.use(cors())
```

(or however your framework does it)

Before trying with your browser again, you can check the response headers in postman to see if the cors headers you are looking for are there:

something like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase you need wrap your whole response callback with the `cors` constant you have created.. .but this looks a lot easier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51922520/5203563

Comment: thanks, wrapping all the functions inside the cors did the trick