# Firebase Cors issue for remote js files

Tags: firebase-hosting

So basically there is a host app which is gets remote microfrontend files from another firebase url.

So remote app is hosted on firebase such as  `www.firebas-ipsum.web.app`.

When host application tries to get file `www.firebas-ipsum.web.app/remoteEntry.js` as expected we received CORS error.

How can we enable CORS for fetching any files?
I tried solution in [CORS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase) but it is for requests, not for files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution by adding headers to `firebase.json.`

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "value": "*"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For more information [Offical Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers)