# Angular 13 Realtime Database with HTTP-Client connection error

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I want this project working with Json-server(localhost:3000) to work with Firebase. However, when I write the firebase link in the url and run the project, I get a CORS error.

json-server working code;

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Employee } from '../shared/employee';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RestApiService {
  // Define API
  apiURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  // Http Options
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }),
  };

  // HttpClient API get() method => Fetch employees list
  getEmployees(): Observable<Employee> {
    return this.http
      .get<Employee>(this.apiURL + '/employees')
      .pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  // HttpClient API get() method => Fetch employee
  getEmployee(id: any): Observable<Employee> {
    return this.http
      .get<Employee>(this.apiURL + '/employees/' + id)
      .pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  // HttpClient API post() method => Create employee
  createEmployee(employee: any): Observable<Employee> {
    return this.http
      .post<Employee>(
        this.apiURL + '/employees',
        JSON.stringify(employee),
        this.httpOptions
      )
      .pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  // HttpClient API put() method => Update employee
  updateEmployee(id: any, employee: any): Observable<Employee> {
    return this.http
      .put<Employee>(
        this.apiURL + '/employees/' + id,
        JSON.stringify(employee),
        this.httpOptions
      )
      .pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  // HttpClient API delete() method => Delete employee
  deleteEmployee(id: any) {
    return this.http
      .delete<Employee>(this.apiURL + '/employees/' + id, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  // Error handling
  handleError(error: any) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // Get client-side error
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
      // Get server-side error
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    window.alert(errorMessage);
    return throwError(() => {
      return errorMessage;
    });
  }
}
```

This is how I do the url change;

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Employee } from '../shared/employee';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RestApiService {
  // Define API
  apiURL = 'https://deneme-8cbfb-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/';

  constru.......
.....
```

I get a CORS error on any transaction(POST, PUT, and DELETE);

(Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://deneme-8cbfb-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app//employees' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.)

(Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED)

Answer (score 1):

As your web application was served by origin http://localhost:4200 and wants to make a request to https://deneme-8cbfb-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app you have to enable cors there.

Here is an example on how to do it: [Enabling CORS in Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase)

Comment: I checked the link you shared. but I don’t know where I should place the CORS codes in my own project shared above. :(