# How do I fix Blocked CORS with Firebase Hosting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have read many threads around this topic and I still can't wrap my head around it.

I've built a web app that allows users to crawl their website sitemap and add it to a document in Firebase. I'm using Firebase hosting to host the web app, which was pushed to a subdomain of mine.

I am using this package to crawl the sitemap - https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-sitemap-links

I get this error every time in production - "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.userswebsite.com/page-sitemap.xml' from origin 'https://app.mywebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I've not created any cloud functions for this web app but have read I have to enable CORS using a function. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you checked this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin)?

Comment: This document doesn't specifically answer my Firebase question. I know I need to enable CORS in the Header but I don't know how to do that with Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

To enable `CORS` you have to install library in your `function` folder by using below command

```
npm i cors --save
```

And import  as shown below :

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
```

You can also set `CORS` headers without any library using below snippet

```
response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

For more information have a look at this [documentation](https://akhromieiev.com/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase/) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42755131/18265570)

If you are [configuring `CORS`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/http-events#configuring_cors_cross-origin_resource_sharing) for HTTP function.  Use the [cors option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/reference/firebase-functions.https.httpsoptions#httpshttpsoptionscors) to control which origins can access your function.

> If true, allows CORS on requests to this function. If this is a string
> or RegExp, allows requests from domains that match the provided value.
> If this is an Array, allows requests from domains matching at least
> one entry of the array. Defaults to true for https.CallableFunction
> and false otherwise.
>
> **Signature:**
> `cors?: string | boolean | RegExp | Array<string | RegExp>;`

Comment: Sorry, what function library?

Comment: @user16034511 Can you elaborate on your question? you mean, which library you should install?

Comment: Which folder? I have my front end web app, reactJS, and then I’ve used firebase hosting for the back end. So I have no folder called function

Comment: you can create `function` folder for `firebase` following this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#initialize-your-project) and you can manage dependencies manually while creating folder

Comment: I've enabled functions to my project, and added this code to my index.js file and deployed.

**exports.fn = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {})
});**

To scrape the users sitemap I'm using this package - GetSitemapLinks(sitemapURL). Is there something I need to do now to call the getsitemaplinks within the function? Or should I not use that package and do something else to scrape sitemaps?

Thanks for your help

Comment: @user16034511 As per this [repo](https://github.com/sromexs/get-sitemap-links) and this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0rZnxRV7_k) you have to call `getsitemaplinks` within the function