# How to avoid CORS on secure way with next.js and cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am using next.js on the frontend side, there is "api" folder that gives us a node.js environment on the next.js server side.

There we can have some proxy "api" between frontend and backend (cloud functions).

1. From frontend side I send request on next.js api
2. From next/api sending request to cloud function
3. Take response and return on frontend side

Result: Got CORS

Next.js api proxy code:

```
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from 'firebase/functions';

import { firebase } from '@/lib';

export async function deleteUserAccount(userId: string) {
  if (!userId) {
    console.error('deleteUserAccount: no userId provided');
    return;
  }

  try {
    const functions = getFunctions(firebase, 'us-central1');
    const deleteUserData = httpsCallable(functions, 'deleteUserData');

    const { data }: any = await deleteUserData({
      userId,
    });

    console.log('deleteUserAccount', data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('deleteUserAccount error', error);
  }
}
```

This is cloud function implementation:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.deleteUserData = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const uid = request.auth.uid;
    
    try {
        await admin.auth().deleteUser(uid);
        return { message: 'Data deleted successfully!' };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error deleting user data', error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
});
```

How to solve CORS in a secure way?

Answer (score 0):

The firebase repository explaining the use of cors in two of their examples. Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase?rq=2)
Just make sure you use this format

```json
{
origin:"https://your-site.name"
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the format. is this ".name" matter? Should I just copy "https:domain.com" ? let's say my domain name is "https://test.me/" how should I format this?

Comment: Even If is put "origin: true" still got CORS, I checked logs there is not another error...